# Finding all maxima and minima of a function

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

To find all (global and local) extrema of a function in $\mathbb R^3$, I have written the following.

Example function:

```
n = 2.;

terrain[x_, y_] :=  2 (2 - x)^2 Exp[-(x^2) - (y + 1)^2] - 
  15 (x/5 - x^3 - y^3) Exp[-x^2 - y^2] - 1/3 Exp[-(x + 1)^2 - y^2];

fun = terrain[x, y];

plot = Plot3D[fun, {x, -n, n}, {y, -n, n}, PlotRange -> All,
              ColorFunction -> "DarkTerrain", Mesh -> False,
              PlotStyle -> Opacity@0.7]
```

[image: plot of terrain function]

One can observe 3 maxima and 3 minima.

```
NMaximize[fun, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {6.4547, {x -> -0.3593, y -> -0.5519}}
> ```

And

```
FindMaximum[fun, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {6.1972, {x -> -0.0529, y -> 1.2130}}
> ```

returns two of the maxima, but misses the third. My idea then was to map `NMaximize`over "sufficient sectors" of the function:

```
 p = Flatten /@ Tuples[Partition[Range[-n, n], 2, 1], 2]
```

> ```
> {{-2., -1., -2., -1.}, {-2., -1., -1., 0.}, ... , {1., 2., 1., 2.}}
> ```

(This algorithm was kindly provided by Kuba)

The next steps are:

```
max1 = NMaximize[{fun, p[[#, 1]] <= x <= p[[#, 2]], p[[#, 3]] <= y <= p[[#, 4]]},
                 {x, y}] & /@ Range@Length@p;
max2 = Chop@Partition[Cases[max1, _Real, Infinity], 3];
```

The result contains wrong points at the edges of the sectors, which can be deleted with

```
filter = # || (# /. b -> c) &[Or @@ MapThread[Equal,
         {Table[b, {n*2 + 1}], Range[-n, n]}]]
```

> ```
> b == -2. || b == -1. || b == 0. || b == 1. || b == 2. || c == -2. ||  
> c == -1. || c == 0. || c == 1. || c == 2.
> ```

```
max3 = DeleteCases[max2, {_, b_, c_} /; Evaluate@filter]
```

> ```
> {{6.45471, -0.359311, -0.551929}, {6.19724, -0.0529807, 1.21301},
>  {5.4426, 1.26211, -0.0152309}}
> ```

which now gives us the three maxima.

```
maxpoints = Graphics3D[{PointSize@0.05, Point /@ RotateLeft /@ max3}]
```

Repeating `max1` through `max3` with `NMinimize` finally gives this image:

[image: density plot with extrema]

Summing - up:

```
extrema[foo_, maxmin_, color_] :=
 Module[{res},
  res = maxmin[{foo, p[[#, 1]] <= x <= p[[#, 2]], 
       p[[#, 3]] <= y <= p[[#, 4]]}, {x, y}] & /@ Range@Length@p;
  res = Chop@Partition[Cases[res, _Real, Infinity], 3];
  res = DeleteCases[res, {a_, b_, c_} /; Evaluate@filter];
  Graphics3D[{color, PointSize@0.05, Point /@ RotateLeft /@ res}]]

Show[plot, extrema[fun, NMaximize, Black], 
 extrema[fun, NMinimize, Red], ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}]
```

Although my approach works, it is pretty slow (more than 2 seconds to find the extrema); and, having found it only by trial and error, I am not sure if this solution is general enough.

I would welcome any comments on how to improve this.

Comment: There are two related posts: [How do I determine the maximum value for a polynomial, given a range of x values?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37225/how-do-i-determine-the-maximum-value-for-a-polynomial-given-a-range-of-x-values/37227#37227) and [How can I implement the method of Lagrange multipliers to find constrained extrema?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36847/how-can-i-implement-the-method-of-lagrange-multipliers-to-find-constrained-extre/36854#36854)

Comment: This is probably related  too ?http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9928/1089

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
n = 2.;
terrain[x_, y_] := 2 (2 - x)^2 Exp[-(x^2) - (y + 1)^2] - 
    15 (x/5 - x^3 - y^3) Exp[-x^2 - y^2] - 1/3 Exp[-(x + 1)^2 - y^2];
sol[x0_, y0_] := {x, y} /. FindRoot[
    Evaluate@{D[terrain[x, y], x] == 0, D[terrain[x, y], y] == 0}, {x,x0}, {y, y0}];
d = 0.5;
data = Table[sol[x0, y0], {x0, -n, n, d}, {y0, -n, n, d}] // Flatten[#, 1] & //
    Select[#, Function[num, Max@Abs@num < n]] & //
    DeleteDuplicates@Round[#, 10.^-6] & // Quiet;
secx[x_, y_] := Evaluate[D[terrain[x, y], {x, 2}]];
secy[x_, y_] := Evaluate[D[terrain[x, y], {y, 2}]]
secxy[x_, y_] := Evaluate[D[terrain[x, y], {x, 1}, {y, 1}]]
delta[x_, y_] := secx[x, y] secy[x, y] - secxy[x, y]^2
min = Select[data, delta @@ # > 0 && secx @@ # > 0 && secy @@ # > 0 &];
max = Select[data, delta @@ # > 0 && secx @@ # < 0 && secy @@ # < 0 &];
ContourPlot[terrain[x, y], {x, -n, n}, {y, -n, n}, Contours -> 20, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 300, 
  Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize[0.03], Point[min], Red, Point[max]}]
```

[image: contour plot with critical points]

`NSolve` can not solve your functions, so I can only use `FindRoot` to find the maxima and minima.

Comment: thank you so much - your solution is much faster than my attempt, it is more "mathematical", and therefore easier to read.

Comment: I have a function that is set up by a combination of different functions employing associations and switch statements, some of them use delayed evaluation (`:=`) and may contain vectors (`{{a},{b},{c}}`). All of the presented approaches produce only an empty list as a result `{}` (after longer or shorter computation time). Within the given range there are extrema that should be found.
Do associations, switch or delayed evaluation cause those problems and how can I avoid them? Any hint (e.g. a link to an explanation) would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

Not ideal but just for fun.

```
fun[a_, b_] := {x, y} /. 
  FindRoot[D[terrain[x, y], {{x, y}}] == {0, 0}, {{x, a}, {y, b}}]
h[a_, b_] := D[terrain[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}] /. {x -> a, y -> b};
pts = DeleteDuplicates[fun @@@ Tuples[Range[-2, 2, 0.5], 2]];
ptsp = Pick[pts, -2 < #[[1]] < 2 && -2 < #[[2]] < 2 & /@ pts];
col[x_, y_] := 
 If[Det[h[x, y]] < 0, {Yellow, PointSize[0.02], Point[{x, y}]}, 
  If[h[x, y][[1, 1]] > 0, {Red, PointSize[0.02], 
    Point[{x, y}]}, {Green, PointSize[0.02], Point[{x, y}]}]]
col3[x_, y_] := 
 If[Det[h[x, y]] < 0, {Yellow, PointSize[0.02], 
   Point[{x, y, terrain[x, y]}]}, 
  If[h[x, y][[1, 1]] > 0, {Red, PointSize[0.02], 
    Point[{x, y, terrain[x, y]}]}, {Green, PointSize[0.02], 
    Point[{x, y, terrain[x, y]}]}]]
```

Visualizing:

```
cp = ContourPlot[terrain[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   Contours -> 10, Epilog -> col @@@ ptsp, 
   ColorFunction -> "DarkTerrain", ImageSize -> 300];
p3 = Show[
   Plot3D[terrain[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> "DarkTerrain", PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7]], 
   Graphics3D[col3 @@@ ptsp], ImageSize -> 300];
Framed@Row[{cp, p3, 
   PointLegend[{Yellow, Red, Green}, {"Saddle", "Local Min", 
     "Local Max"}]}]
```

[image]

Uses:

- `FindRoot` to find critical points
- Filtering results by `DeleteDuplicates`and constraining zeros to $[-2,2]\times[-2,2]$ (to avoid 'the flatlands')
- using second partial derivative test to classify (by color) critical points

Comment: +1, Your solution reminded me of a painting as an art and as an inspiration for a different approach. Thank you! Oh yeah, the painting, [The Scream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scream).

Comment: @Lou yes, now that you comment on it, the contour plot with DarkTerrain is reminiscent of the face in 'The Scream' or the tilted head of an ET like alien!  Thanks for +1 and observation :)

Comment: Thanks for this new approach and for adding the saddle points, +1

Comment: @eldo it is very similar to other answer but just thought it would be useful to exploit way to calculate Hessian etc. Thank you for +1 :)

Answer (score 9):

Here is my modest contribution. The idea is to use the `MeshFunctions` option of `ContourPlot[]` (as previously shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46569)) to extract the critical points for polishing with `FindRoot[]`. The Hessian is then evaluated at these points, and then tested for definiteness to identify what kind of critical points they are.

```
terrain[x_, y_] := 2 (2 - x)^2 Exp[-(x^2) - (y + 1)^2] -
        15 (x/5 - x^3 - y^3) Exp[-x^2 - y^2] - 1/3 Exp[-(x + 1)^2 - y^2]

{dx[x_, y_], dy[x_, y_]} = D[terrain[x, y], {{x, y}}];
hes[x_, y_] = D[terrain[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}];

crit = Cases[Normal[ContourPlot[dx[x, y] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
                                ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{0}},
                                MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, dy[x, y]]]], 
             Point[{x0_, y0_}] :> ({\[FormalX], \[FormalY]} /. 
             FindRoot[{dx[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]], dy[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]]},
                      {{\[FormalX], x0}, {\[FormalY], y0}}]), ∞];

hl = hes @@@ crit;
mnp = PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ hl; (* pick minima *)
mxp = PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ (-hl); (* pick maxima *)
sdp = Thread[mnp ⊽ mxp]; (* saddle points are leftovers *)

mini = Pick[crit, mnp]; maxi = Pick[crit, mxp]; sadl = Pick[crit, sdp];

{Legended[ContourPlot[terrain[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
                      ColorFunction -> "DarkTerrain", Contours -> 10, 
                      Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], {Cyan, Point[mini]},
                                 {Yellow, Point[sadl]}, {Orange, Point[maxi]}}], 
          PointLegend[{Cyan, Yellow, Orange}, {"Minima", "Saddles", "Maxima"}]],
 Show[Plot3D[terrain[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
             BoundaryStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, 
             ColorFunction -> "DarkTerrain", Mesh -> 10, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}],
      Graphics3D[{{Cyan, Sphere[mini, 1/20]}, {Yellow, Sphere[sadl, 1/20]},
                  {Orange, Sphere[maxi, 1/20]}} /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :>
                  {x, y, terrain[x, y]}]]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: she'll be comin' 'round the mountain...]

Comment: I was going to do something like this, but in the process, I came up with a better answer to [one of your questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275/updating-wagons-findallcrossings2d-function/97898#97898)

Comment: Just saw it; will upvote when I can do so again.

Comment: @J.M. I really like this...thank you for yet another lesson :-)

Comment: @ubpdqn, you're welcome! This site's great for scratching my teaching itch. :)

Comment: Not that important but one thing I was going to do different is `Total@*Sign@*Eigenvalues /@ hl` and use ±2, 0 for the `Pick` selection patterns for the min/max/saddle.

Comment: @Michael, that works, too. The difference in effort doesn't matter much in this specific $2\times 2$ case, but in general Cholesky decompositions (used internally for checking definiteness) are cheaper to do than eigendecompositions.

Comment: As it should be, considering that only 2 of the 2^n cases yield extrema. As I said, not that important.

Comment: May I just ask 3 things: (1) in order for `Cases` to work, the first argument needs to be an expression. So what does `ContourPlot` return, since I can only see it as a plot? A list, an equation? How do I see it? (2) what is the `RuleDelayed` doing exactly and why does it not work with a normal `Rule`? (3) What significance does `levelspec` have for `Cases`? I've been looking through examples and cannot understand what that number corresponds to...

Comment: @Super, 1. `ContourPlot[]` returns a `Graphics[]` expression, as can be seen by evaluating `InputForm[ContourPlot[(* stuff *)]]`. 2. `:>` prevents immediate evaluation of the rule's right-hand side; basically, you don't want `FindRoot[]` to act immediately until the relevant expressions have already been inserted. 3. In this specific case, I wanted to extract all the `Point[]` objects within `Graphics[]` without having to worry how deeply they are buried in the expression, so I put in `∞` as the level specification.

Comment: @J.M.'sennui Has Mathematica changed the output of `ContourPlot` with new versions? Running this code now returns `crit = {}`.

Comment: @Super, I think it's a bug you should report to Support. A simpler example would be `cp = Normal[ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, x - y]]]`; evaluating `Cases[cp, _Point, ∞]` returns `{}` in the current version when it should be returning a `Point[]`.