# Maxima turn out to be false maxima when extremising function locally

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, mathematical-optimization, code-review

In short:
I have a 2-D function that gives this plot, where the orange dots are maxima:
[image: contour plot]
[image: surface plot]

There are 4 maxima in this plot.

Now, I plot the function again in a smaller region, close to these maxima, resulting in this [image: this]:

**So, one of the maxima turned out to be fake.**

How can I change the main code to better extremise the function (when it is on a larger area, like the first picture) and *not* return false maxima?

Thanks so much.

---

Code:

```
k = 2 π;
k1 = {k, 0};
k2 = FullSimplify[RotationMatrix[(2 π)/5]. k1];
k3 = FullSimplify[RotationMatrix[(2 π)/5]. k2];
k4 = FullSimplify[RotationMatrix[(2 π)/5] .k3];
k5 = FullSimplify[RotationMatrix[(2 π)/5] .k4];
E1[x_, y_, I1_, α1_] := Sqrt[I1] Exp[I k1.{x, y} - α1]
E2[x_, y_, I1_, α1_] := Sqrt[I1] Exp[I k2.{x, y} - α1]
E3[x_, y_, I1_, α1_] := Sqrt[I1] Exp[I k3.{x, y} - α1]
E4[x_, y_, I1_, α1_] := Sqrt[I1] Exp[I k4.{x, y} - α1]
E5[x_, y_, I1_, α1_] := Sqrt[I1] Exp[I k5.{x, y} - α1]
Eges[x_, y_] := 
 E1[x, y, 1, 0] + E2[x, y, 1, 0] + E3[x, y, 1, 0] + E4[x, y, 1, 0] + 
  E5[x, y, 1, 0]
IIges[x_, y_] := 
  Conjugate[Eges[x, y]] Eges[x, y] // ComplexExpand // 
   Simplify; (* can't differentiate Conjugate, had to change this *)
xm = 4; 

{dx[x_, y_], dy[x_, y_]} = 
  D[IIges[x, y], {{x, y}}]; (* calculating partial derivatives *)
hes[x_, y_] = 
  D[IIges[x, y], {{x, y}, 
    2}]; (* Hessian matrix: Second derivative matrix *)

crit = Cases[
   Normal[ContourPlot[dx[x, y] == 0, {x, -xm, xm}, {y, -xm, xm}, 
     ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
     MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, dy[x, y]]]], 
   Point[{x0_, y0_}] :> ({\[FormalX], \[FormalY]} /. 
      FindRoot[{dx[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]], 
        dy[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]]}, {{\[FormalX], x0}, {\[FormalY], 
         y0}}]),  ∞];

(* Identify points as minima, maxima or saddle points *)
hl = hes @@@ crit;
mnp = PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ hl; (*pick minima*)
mxp = PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ (-hl); (*pick maxima*)
sdp = Thread[mnp ⊽ mxp];(*saddle points are leftovers*)

(* Finding coordinates of critical points *)
mini = Pick[crit, mnp];
maxi = Pick[crit, mxp];
sadl = Pick[crit, sdp];

(* Plot stuff!
I changed the Image Size because it was too small *)
{Legended[
  ContourPlot[IIges[x, y], {x, -xm, xm}, {y, -xm, xm}, 
   ImageSize -> Scaled[0.3], ColorFunction -> "DarkTerrain", 
   Contours -> 15, 
   Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], {Cyan, Point[mini]}, {Orange, 
      Point[maxi]}}], 
  PointLegend[{Cyan, Orange}, {"Minima", "Maxima"}]], 
 Show[Plot3D[IIges[x, y], {x, -xm, xm}, {y, -xm, xm}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> "DarkTerrain", Mesh -> 15, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}], 
  Graphics3D[{{Cyan, Sphere[mini, 1/20]}, {Orange, 
      Sphere[maxi, 1/20]}} /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, y, 
      IIges[x, y]}], ImageSize -> Scaled[0.43]]}

crit2 = Cases[
   Normal[ContourPlot[dx[x, y] == 0, {x, 0.5, 2}, {y, -2.5, -1}, 
     ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
     MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, dy[x, y]]]], 
   Point[{x0_, y0_}] :> ({\[FormalX], \[FormalY]} /. 
      FindRoot[{dx[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]], 
        dy[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]]}, {{\[FormalX], x0}, {\[FormalY], 
         y0}}]), ∞];
hl2 = hes @@@ crit2;
mnp2 = PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ hl2; (*pick minima*)
mxp2 = PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ (-hl2); (*pick maxima*)
sdp2 = Thread[mnp2 ⊽ mxp2];(*saddle points are leftovers*)

mini2 = Pick[crit2, mnp2];
maxi2 = Pick[crit2, mxp2];
sadl2 = Pick[crit2, sdp2];

{Legended[
  ContourPlot[IIges[x, y], {x, 0.5, 2}, {y, -2.5, -1}, 
   ImageSize -> Scaled[0.3], ColorFunction -> "DarkTerrain", 
   Contours -> 15, 
   Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], {Cyan, Point[mini2]}, {Orange, 
      Point[maxi2]}}], 
  PointLegend[{Cyan, Orange}, {"Minima", "Maxima"}]], 
 Show[Plot3D[IIges[x, y], {x, 0.5, 2}, {y, -2.5, -1}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> "DarkTerrain", Mesh -> 15, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}], 
  Graphics3D[{{Cyan, Sphere[mini2, 1/20]}, {Orange, 
      Sphere[maxi2, 1/20]}} /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, y, 
      IIges[x, y]}], ImageSize -> Scaled[0.43]]}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't quite feel like writing out the full solution. Nevertheless, I see that you're trying your best to adapt [one of my previous solutions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97892), and I will at least show a way for you to work a little bit smarter.

One of the tenets of numerical computing is the one of **exploiting the structure of the problem**; what this says is that you look if there is any structure like symmetry that can be used to reduce computational effort, improve numerical stability, or even both.

In your particular case, I previously gave you a hint: `Conjugate[Eges[x, y]] == Eges[-x, -y]`. Apart from the obvious advantage of not needing to differentiate `Conjugate[]` anymore, it's a clue that *your objective function has twofold symmetry*.

Another exploitable fact is in how your function was built: one can see that *the function ought to have five-fold symmetry*. Put those two facts together, and we find that **the objective function is ten-fold ($\mathbf{5\times2}$) symmetric**.

How to exploit this, you ask? This means we can concentrate all our computational efforts within a wedge of the plane, and later reproduce all the solutions through suitable rotations.

Thankfully, `ContourPlot[]` supports a `RegionFunction` option, which allows you to restrict effort to just a slice of the whole pie.

Here is how you can start. Note that I have simplified the generation of the objective function:

```
Clear[x, y];
k1 = {2 π, 0}; rots = RootReduce[NestList[RotationTransform[2 π/5], k1, 4]];
Eges[x_, y_, I1_: 1, a1_: 0] = Sqrt[I1] Total[Exp[I rots.{x, y} - a1]];
IIges[x_, y_] = Simplify[ComplexExpand[Re[Eges[-x, -y] Eges[x, y]]]];

{dx[x_, y_], dy[x_, y_]} = D[IIges[x, y], {{x, y}}];
hes[x_, y_] = D[IIges[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}];

(* note how RegionFunction "slices the pie" *)
crit = Cases[Normal[ContourPlot[dx[x, y] == 0, {x, -4 Sqrt[2], 4 Sqrt[2]},
                                {y, -4 Sqrt[2], 4 Sqrt[2]}, 
                                ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{0}},
                                MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, dy[x, y]],
                                PlotPoints -> 75, RegionFunction ->
                                Function[{x, y, z}, 0 < Arg[x + I y] < π/5 &&
                                         Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 4 Sqrt[2]]]], 
             Point[{x0_, y0_}] :> ({\[FormalX], \[FormalY]} /. 
             FindRoot[{dx[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]], dy[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]]},
                      {{\[FormalX], x0}, {\[FormalY], y0}}]), ∞];

hl = hes @@@ crit;
mnp = PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ hl; (* pick minima *)
mxp = PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ (-hl); (* pick maxima *)
mini = Pick[crit, mnp]; maxi = Pick[crit, mxp];
```

Visualize the solutions in the chosen wedge:

```
ContourPlot[IIges[x, y], {x, 0, 4 Sqrt[2]}, {y, 0, 4 Sqrt[2] Sin[π/5]}, 
            AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", 
            Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[5],
                       {Orange, Point[mini]}, {Green, Point[maxi]}},
            PlotPoints -> 45,
            RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 < Arg[x + I y] < π/5 &&
                                       Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 4 Sqrt[2]]]
```

[image: a slice of the pie, with some toppings]

A perceptive eye will notice two things: the origin was missed even though it was a critical point (not too hard to fix), and some of the points in one edge of the "slice" were also captured in the other edge. For that second caveat, this means that when you do the rotation later to reproduce all the critical points, you will have to strip out some duplicates. Still, not having to look at too many critical points is a big thing, and we are lucky that symmetry allows this simplification.

Comment: (+1) You have generated a segment of a very nice snowflake-like texture! Festive mood! :) I would appreciate if you post the complete figure.

Comment: In due time, @Alexey. In due time. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I did  not want to assume any symmetry a priori, I would have rather wanted to see it from the plot. Thanks though!

Comment: @Super, "did not want to assume any symmetry" - well, the symmetry only was determined by looking at the properties of the function; no assumptions apart from $x,y$ being real was used. The plot merely confirms the ten-fold symmetry. In any event, it would be wasteful not to try doing some analytical legwork before plunging into numerics.

Comment: My interest actually lied in a larger plot, xm = 8. If you plot that, little pentagons arise, but sometimes they are "missing a point". In the small plot (xm=4), these 'broken pentagons' look like the figure circled in red in the first picture.
Since I was not sure whether or not to expect these pentagons, I focussed on a small region (this question) and tried to see whether the 'extra points' that I saw actually belonged to rhombs or pentagons.

Comment: Nevertheless, thanks for your question. Now that I now what to expect I will definitely use symmetry.

Comment: The analysis I did here carries over to the larger region you are interested in, @Super. If you look at my code closely, I in fact expanded the region a little bit ($4\sqrt{2}$) so that the wedge will cover the square after rotation. If you're truly paranoid about coverage, in addition to the wedge from $0$ to $\pi/5$, you can try the wedge from $-\pi/10$ to $\pi/10$ as a confirmatory check.

Answer (score 8):

The extraneous points result from inadequate resolution in the `ContourPlot` used to provide initial estimates for `crit`.  A simple but effective approach is to increase `PlotPoints`.

```
ContourPlot[dx[x, y] == 0, {x, -xm, xm}, {y, -xm, xm}, PlotPoints -> 50,
    ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, dy[x, y]]]
```

[image: critical points]

This change reduces `Length[crit]` from `895` to `853` and also eliminates numerous `FindRoot::lstol:` error messages.