# What do the lines in a ContourPlot Mean?

Tags: plotting

If you plot a two variable function like $x^2+y^2$, you get a series of circles with lines and colored areas. My question is, what do the lines and the colored areas represent?

Comment: Try this experiment: `ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]`, followed by `Plot3D[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]` and compare the two. Now try `ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -4, 4 }, {y, -4, 4 }]` and `Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -4, 4 }, {y, -4, 4 }]`. Got it? `ContourPlot` by default generates colorized grayscale output, in which larger values are shown lighter. You may also like to read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line and http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/contour.htm

Comment: @Moo, OK, so now I know why there are areas of different colors but what is the meaning if the lines  bounding each colored area? Do they represent something?

Comment: It's explained well here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line  The value of the function doesn't change as you move along a contour.

Comment: @MrDi: There needs to be a way to select peaks and valleys and to bound them somehow, so they use some algorithm that picks those areas. I think you can find some details on the Wiki link I provided. it sounds like you get it, think of it as trying to collapse a 3D image onto a 2D surface. These diagrams can be extremely useful. The lines are just separating areas where something is changing based on some algorithm.

Comment: @Moo, OK, thanks for help.

Answer (score 5):

It might be easier for you to see the correspondence between a contour plot and a surface plot if you plot them side-by-side like this (code adapted from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97892)):

```
peaks[x_, y_] := 3 (1 - x)^2 Exp[-x^2 - (y + 1)^2] - 10 (x/5 - x^3 - y^5) Exp[-x^2 - y^2] -
                 Exp[-(x + 1)^2 - y^2]/3

With[{c = Subdivide[-5, 5, 10]}, 
     GraphicsRow[{ContourPlot[peaks[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
                              ColorFunction -> "DarkTerrain",
                              Contours -> c, PlotRange -> All], 
                  Plot3D[peaks[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
                         Boxed -> False, ColorFunction -> "DarkTerrain", 
                         MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {c}, PlotRange -> All, 
                         ViewPoint -> {0, -2.7, 3.}]}]]
```

[image: some interesting terrain]

where I took the opportunity to use a function with more interesting contours. (Unfortunately, I don't know of any way to refine the meshlines produced by `MeshFunctions`; if you know a way, let me know in the comments!)

As noted in the comments above, the contours in `ContourPlot[]` are so-called *isoclines*; that is, lines of constant altitude ($z$ value). The interpretation of the colors depends on what colormap you're using; in this case, I used the `"DarkTerrain"` color gradient, which goes like this:

[image: "DarkTerrain" color gradient]

where the bluish color ("water") corresponds to the valleys, the whitish color ("snowcap") corresponds to the peaks, and the earthy colors corresponds to intermediate values. If you are familiar with [map reading](http://www.compassdude.com/topographic-maps.php), running along isoclines corresponds to staying at a constant (flat) altitude, and crossing the isoclines corresponds to either ascent or descent.

---

A biographical segue: I was a Boy Scout once upon a time, and map reading was *de rigueur* for Scouts who wanted to have camping experience.