# Finding the minima and the transition state in a potential energy surface (PES)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

*Problem Background:*

I am trying to simulate a potential energy surface (PES) which represents the different states that a triatomic molecule (A-B-C) can have in 3D and its corresponding `ContourPlot`.

The potential function, depending on the distance between atom A and atom B (which I called `r`) and the distance between atom B an atom C (which I called `d`) has the following form (which I arbitrarily chose):

```
crazypotential =  1/r^12 - 2/r^6 + 1/d^12 - 2/d^6 -
(2 Exp[-(r - d)] + 2Exp[-(d - r)] -  2 Exp[-(2 (r - d) - (d - r))*Cos[d]]);

Plot3D[crazypotential, {r, .8, 1.6}, {d, .8, 1.6}]

Show[ContourPlot[crazypotential, {r, 0.75, 2}, {d, 0.75, 2}, PlotLegends -> Automatic,
                 Contours -> 15, ContourStyle -> Directive[Black, Opacity[.3]],
                 ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"],
     Graphics[Text["Transition State", {1.1, 1.3}]]]
```

[image: This is my PES]
[image]

As you can see, there are clearly two minima and one transition state. Now, my question is the following:

I want to know exactly where the minima (deep blue) and the transition state are. For that I do something like:

```
Solve[D[crazypotential, {r, d}] == 0 && r < 1.6 && d < 1.6, {r, d}, Reals]
```

But does not seem to work. Do you have any ideas about how I could try to solve these minima and transition state in this region (both `r` and `d` going from 0.8 to 1.6)? Or do you see any mistake in my code that could be the reason why it is not working?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you know, what you call "transition state" is in particular a critical point of `crazypotential`, i.e., a point where both partial derivative of `crazypotential` with respect to `r` and `d` vanish. A "root" of the derivative of `crazypotential` so to say.

You already read off a good guess for the transition state. You can refine that with Newton's method which is effectively performed by `FindRoot`.

```
Dcrazypotential = D[crazypotential, {{r, d}, 1}];
FindRoot[Dcrazypotential == {0, 0}, Transpose@{{r, d}, {1.1, 1.3}}]
```

> {r -> 1.01146, d -> 1.31042}

The same is also applicable to the minimizers; they are also roots of `Dcrazypotential` -- if they exist. I have to say that `crayzpotential` is not bounded from below on $\mathbb{R}^2$, so there are no global minimizers. Still, there might exist local minimizers...

If you want to constrain `r` and `d` to lie between `0.8` and `1.8`, then minimimal values are attained at the box boundary. The can be detected with

```
FindRoot[Dcrazypotential[[1]] == 0 /. d -> 1.8, {r, 1.}]
FindRoot[Dcrazypotential[[2]] == 0 /. r -> 1.8, {d, 1.}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Adapting the approach from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97892), here is how to use the `MeshFunctions` option of `ContourPlot[]` to find critical points:

```
potential[r_, d_] := 1/r^12 - 2/r^6 + 1/d^12 - 2/d^6 -
         (2 Exp[-(r - d)] + 2 Exp[-(d - r)] - 2 Exp[-(2 (r - d) - (d - r)) Cos[d]])

(* gradient and Hessian *)
{dr[r_, d_], dd[r_, d_]} = D[potential[r, d], {{r, d}}];
hes[r_, d_] = D[potential[r, d], {{r, d}, 2}];

crit = Cases[Normal[ContourPlot[dr[r, d] == 0, {r, 3/4, 2}, {d, 3/4, 2}, 
                                ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
                                MeshFunctions -> Function[{r, d, f}, dd[r, d]]]], 
             Point[{r0_, d0_}] :> ({\[FormalR], \[FormalD]} /. 
                                   FindRoot[{dr[\[FormalR], \[FormalD]],
                                             dd[\[FormalR], \[FormalD]]},
                                            {{\[FormalR], r0}, {\[FormalD], d0}}]), ∞]
   {{1.01146, 1.31042}}
```

where we see that only one critical point is returned. Let's test it:

```
hc = hes @@ crit[[1]];
Through[{PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ, IndefiniteMatrixQ, NegativeDefiniteMatrixQ}[hc]]
   {False, True, False}
```

This verifies that the point we found is a saddle point.