# How can I better formulate a conditional statement?

Tags: core-language, conditional

To solve optimization problems I have seen this:

[image]

Is there a more elegant way to do this with alternative conditional expressions? Is there something equivelant to `if, elseif, else` that you'd see in Matlab, Maple, RStudio, Ptyhon, etc?

Comment: Are you asking if there's a more elegant version of `If[a, b, If[c, d, e]]`? Would `Which[a, b, c, d, True, e]` qualify?

Comment: `Which[]` and `Switch[]` would be of interest. Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50908)?

Comment: In the future please don't post pictures of code. Please.