# Finding multiple minimizers

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, numerical-value, findinstance

Is it possible to find all (or as many as possible) minimizers of a given function? For example, minimizing the function $\cos(\pi(p-q))+\cos(\pi(q+p))$ for $-3\leq p,q\leq 3 $ can be done using `NMinimize` as follows

```
min = NMinimize[{Cos[Pi (p - q)] + Cos[Pi (q + p)], -3 <= q <= 3 && -3 <= p <= 3}, {q, p}]
```

This yields the answer

```
{-2., {q -> 2., p -> 3.}}
```

Naturally there are more minimizer pairs, for example $p=-2,q=-3$. Is it possible to get all minimizers?

**My attempt:** Once I have the minimum value, `min[[1]]`, I know `FindInstance` takes an argument `n` which allows to find `n` instances, so I guess I could try working with this, and setting, for a large enough `n`,

```
n = 100;
FindInstance[{Cos[Pi (p - q)] + Cos[Pi (q + p)] == min[[1]], -3 <= q <= 3 && -3 <= p <= 3}, {q, p}, n]
```

This finds 24 possible minimizer pairs. For more complex functions, however, **this does not work** (using `N[Rationalize[min[[1]]]]` instead of `min[[1]]` may help). Numerically minimizing will have an associated precision error which depends on the way `NMinimize` internally works, so any help is appreciated. I wonder if there's already an inbuilt or better/fast way of doing it in Mathematica.

**Edit:** I decided to share my main function in [this follow-up question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240940/how-to-show-all-global-minimizers), because it seems that its complexity might suggest different approaches. Please take a look.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50908)?