# Using ContourPlot3D to fine the local extrema of a 3D function

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

[This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97892/35368) shows a neat way of using `ContourPlot` and `MeshFunctions` to find the local extrema of a 2D function: the intersections between contours and meshes give us a rough location for the extrema, which are then computed precisely with `FindRoot`.

A MWE is reported here:

```
IIges[x_, y_] := Sin[x]^2 + Sin[y]^2;
xm = 4;

{dx[x_, y_], dy[x_, y_]} = D[IIges[x, y], {{x, y}}]; 
hes[x_, y_] = D[IIges[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}]; crit = 
 Cases[Normal[
   ContourPlot[dx[x, y] == 0, {x, -xm, xm}, {y, -xm, xm}, 
    ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
    MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, dy[x, y]]]], 
  Point[{x0_, y0_}] :> ({\[FormalX], \[FormalY]} /. 
     FindRoot[{dx[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]], 
       dy[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]]}, {{\[FormalX], x0}, {\[FormalY], 
        y0}}]), \[Infinity]];
```

where `crit` are then the {x,y} coordinates of the extrema (critical points).

The `ContourPlot` bit gives this result:

```
ContourPlot[dx[x, y] == 0, {x, -xm, xm}, {y, -xm, xm}, 
 ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, dy[x, y]]]
```

[image]

which clearly shows that meshes and contours are intersecting at points.

**Question**: how can I extend this to a 3D function with `ContourPlot3D`?

My main problem is that I need to get a grid of 3D points from `ContourPlot3D`, like the image shown above.

But if I do:

```
IIges[x_, y_, z_] := Sin[x]^2 + Sin[y]^2 + Sin[z]^2;
xm = 4;

{dx[x_, y_, z_], dy[x_, y_, z_], dz[x_, y_, z_]} = D[IIges[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}}];

    ContourPlot3D[
     dx[x, y, 0] == 0, {x, -xm, xm}, {y, -xm, xm}, {z, -xm, xm}, 
     ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
     MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, dy[x, y, z]], 
       Function[{x, y, z}, dz[x, y, z]]}]
```

I get this:
[image]

no points, just lines! How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to see the location of the critical points of your `IIges[x_, y_, z_]`, then the following works (The function is periodic in each variable with period  `Pi`.).

```
IIges[x_, y_, z_] := Sin[x]^2 + Sin[y]^2 + Sin[z]^2;
xm = Pi/2 + 0.5;
{dx[x_, y_, z_], dy[x_, y_, z_], dz[x_, y_, z_]} =  D[IIges[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}}];
ContourPlot3D[dx[x, y, z]^2 + dy[x, y, z]^2 + dz[x, y, z]^2 == 0.01,
{x, -xm, xm}, {y, -xm, xm}, {z, -xm, xm}, PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but then I would like a list of points near the real critical points so that I can use FindRoot on that pattern

Comment: @SuperCiocia: Searh   "Extracting data from plot" in this forum (at the top of this page). Good luck!