# Finding maximum or minimum of implicit functions

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

is there any built in function that can be used to find maximum or minimum of implicit functions?

For example, if we have the equation
$$x^2 + y^2 = (2 x^2 + 2 y^2 - x)^2,$$
then we can visualize the set of all $(x,y)$ making the equation true using `ContourPlot`.

```
ContourPlot[
 x^2 + y^2 == (2 x^2 + 2 y^2 - x)^2, {x, -1, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Clearly, $y$ is not a function of $x$ but, in the neighborhood of most points on the graph, a function is *implied*, i.e. $y$ is implicitly a function of $x$.  Is there any built in way to find the maximum and/or minimum value of this function (like what we have for the explicit functions)?

Comment: @Algohi - I've edited your question.  Please make sure that I've retained your intended meaning.

Comment: @MarkMcClure yes you have. thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Maximize[{y, x^2 + y^2 == (2 x^2 + 2 y^2 - x)^2}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {(3 Sqrt[3])/8, {x -> 3/8, y -> (3 Sqrt[3])/8}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks. this is the solution I am looking for.

Comment: @Algohi This approach may omit some solutions (not the case here) see e.g. [How do I determine the maximum value for a polynomial, given a range of x values?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37225/how-do-i-determine-the-maximum-value-for-a-polynomial-given-a-range-of-x-values/37227#37227) therefore in general one shouldn't forget abour Lagrange multipliers as in Mark's  answer. Take also a closer look at [the method of Lagrange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36847/how-can-i-implement-the-method-of-lagrange-multipliers-to-find-constrained-extre/36854#36854)

Answer (score 13):

You could use Lagrange multipliers to maximize $f(x,y)=y$ subject to the constraint that
$$g(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - (2 x^2 + 2 y^2 - x)^2 = 0.$$

```
f[x_, y_] = y;
g[x_, y_] = x^2 + y^2 - (2 x^2 + 2 y^2 - x)^2;
eqs = {D[f[x, y], x] == lambda*D[g[x, y], x],
  D[f[x, y], y] == lambda*D[g[x, y], y], g[x, y] == 0};
Solve[eqs, {x, y, lambda}] // InputForm

(* Out: {
  {x -> 3/8, y -> (-3*Sqrt[3])/8, lambda -> 2/(3*Sqrt[3])}, 
  {x -> 3/8, y -> (3*Sqrt[3])/8, lambda -> -2/(3*Sqrt[3])}}
*)
```

The maximum value of $y$ is $3\sqrt{3}/8 \approx 0.6495$.  Of course, this should occur where the proper contour of $y$ is tangent to the restraint curve.  You can visualize the situation like so.

```
contourPic = ContourPlot[y, {x, -1, 2}, {y, -1, 1},
  Contours -> Range[-2, 2, 1/2]*3 Sqrt[3]/8];
restraintPic  = ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 - (2 x^2 + 2 y^2 - x)^2 == 0, 
  {x, -1, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, ContourStyle -> {Thick, Black}];
Show[{contourPic, restraintPic}, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[{3/8, 3 Sqrt[3]/8}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Even better if you would also show the maximum in x-direction (1 or near 1) and the minima.

Comment: @Mark McClure, thanks for the solution. I was looking from some built in function but thanks for suggesting Lagrange multipliers.

Answer (score 9):

In version 10,

```
RegionBounds@ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == (2 x^2 + 2 y^2 - x)^2, {x, y}]

(* {{-(1/8), 1}, {-((3 Sqrt[3])/8), (3 Sqrt[3])/8}} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

This implicit equation is simple enough to be converted to explicit equations

```
eqn = x^2 + y^2 == (2 x^2 + 2 y^2 - x)^2;

yExpr = (y /. Solve[eqn, y]);

yMax = SortBy[Maximize[#, x] & /@ yExpr, N[First[#]] &][[-1, 1]];

yMin = SortBy[Minimize[#, x] & /@ yExpr, N[First[#]] &][[1, 1]];

xExpr = (x /. Solve[{eqn, yMin < y < yMax}, x, Reals]) // 
   Simplify[#, yMin < y < yMax] &;

xMax = SortBy[Maximize[#, y] & /@ xExpr // Quiet, N[First[#]] &][[-1, 1]];

xMin = SortBy[Minimize[#, y] & /@ xExpr, N[First[#]] &][[1, 1]];

ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[{eqn, x == xMin, x == xMax, y == yMin, y == yMax}],
 {x, -1, 2}, {y, -1, 1},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: for this equation yes. but I was asking in general. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Also just for fun (in case you don't like to solve equations):

```
cp = ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == (2 x^2 + 2 y^2 - x)^2, {x, -1, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic];

x = Cases[cp, {_Real, _Real}, Infinity];

points = Point /@ {Take[SortBy[x, First], 2], First@SortBy[x, Last],
    Last@SortBy[x, First], Last@SortBy[x, Last]};

Show[cp, Graphics[{PointSize@0.025, points}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I post this just for fun. It does not address the general question of maximizing implicit function but Kuba has shown how to maximize y subject to constraint f(x,y).

The problem can (with a small amount of manipulation) converted to explicit polar form: $r=0.5(cos\theta+1)$. Using this:

```
rho[t_] := (Cos[t] + 1)/2;
ycrit = Solve[D[Cos[u] Sin[u] + Sin[u], u] == 0, u]
xcrit = Solve[D[Cos[u]^2 + Cos[u], u] == 0, u]
pol = PolarPlot[0.5 (Cos[t] + 1), {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #3 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{Pi/3, Pi, 2 Pi - Pi/3}, {0, 2 Pi/3, 2 Pi - 2 Pi/3}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {{Red, PointSize[0.02]}, {Blue, PointSize[0.02]}}]
max = rho[#] {Cos[#], Sin[#]} &[Pi/3]
```

The y critical points are the maximum, the cusp and minmum:

{{u -> ConditionalExpression[-([Pi]/3) + 2 [Pi] C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDlmk.png), 
    C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDlmk.png) [Element] Integers]}, {u -> 
   ConditionalExpression[[Pi]/3 + 2 [Pi] C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDlmk.png), 
    C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDlmk.png) [Element] Integers]}, {u -> 
   ConditionalExpression[[Pi] + 2 [Pi] C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDlmk.png), 
    C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDlmk.png) [Element] Integers]}}

The x critical points:
{{u -> ConditionalExpression[2 [Pi] C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDlmk.png), 
    C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDlmk.png) [Element] Integers]}, {u -> 
   ConditionalExpression[-((2 [Pi])/3) + 2 [Pi] C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDlmk.png), 
    C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDlmk.png) [Element] Integers]}, {u -> 
   ConditionalExpression[(2 [Pi])/3 + 2 [Pi] C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDlmk.png), 
    C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDlmk.png) [Element] Integers]}, {u -> 
   ConditionalExpression[[Pi] + 2 [Pi] C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDlmk.png), 
    C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDlmk.png) [Element] Integers]}}

The visualization:

[image]

The maximum:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Reduce[x^2+y^2==(2 x^2+2 y^2-x)^2,{y},{x},Reals]
```

> -((3 Sqrt[3])/8) <= y <= (3 Sqrt[3])/8

Answer (score 1):

You function is

```
f = x^2 + y^2 - (2 x^2 + 2 y^2 - x)^2;
```

Then call function `Maximize`

```
Maximize[f, {x, y}]
(*{27/64,{x->3/4,y->0}}*)
```

And here is plot of you function

[image]

Comment: That is different than what I meant. you have changed the function from 2D to 3D which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = x^2 + y^2 - (2 x^2 + 2 y^2 - x)^2;

points =
  Catenate[{x, y} /. 
    MapThread[Solve[{f == 0, -D[f, #1]/D[f, #2] == 0}, {x, y}, Reals] &, {{x, y}, {y, x}}]]
```

[image]

```
grid = Union /@ Transpose@points;

ContourPlot[f == 0, {x, -1/2, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 Epilog -> {PointSize@Large, Point@points},
 FrameTicks -> Join[grid, {None, None}],
 GridLines -> grid]
```

[image]