# Minimum of explicit functions in vector form

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

For fun, related to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51679/finding-maximum-or-minimum-of-implicit-functions) about minimizing implicit functions, how can I find the minimum of an explicit one *expressed as a vector*?

For instance, an ellipse:

```
orbit[t_] := 
{
   a Cos[2 \[Pi] t/10],
   b Sin[2 \[Pi] t/10]
}
```

I am finding hard to adapt those solutions for vectors, apart from the obvious solution of minimizing **two** functions, but I'd like a more elegant vector-like solution if possible, something like

```
Maximize[{magicHere, orbit[t]}, t]
```

Comment: This is an explicit (parametrized function from the line to the plane. What is it that needs to be minimized?

Comment: The components of the function (sorry for the wrong characterization, I corrected the question) with respect to `t`.

Comment: There are two functions, and they have an algebraic dependency. So they cannot be simultaneously minimized.

Comment: So, maybe numerically with `NMaximize` should do the trick?

Comment: It remains unclear what is wanted. Without that, I for one cannot suggest what functions to use.