# Maximize a variable in NSolve Function

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I want to solve a set of trigometric coupled equations with the `NSolve` funcion while at the same time trying to maximize a variable which has to be real and between $0$ to $1$.

```
NSolve[ Cos[x1]Cos[x3]-a==0 && Sin[x2]Cos[x1]-a==0 && Sin[x3]Cos[x1]+a==0, {x1,x2,x3,a}]
```

The variable that I want to maximize is `a`.

The input equations  are a simplified version. There is a solution to my actual equations with `a = 0.5`.

The real problems is,

```
NSolve[ Cos[x1] Cos[x2] Cos[x3] - Sin[x1] Sin[x3] == a && 
       Cos[x1]^2 Cos[x2] Cos[2 x3] - Cos[x2] Cos[2 x3] Sin[x1]^2 - 2 Cos[x1] (1 + Cos[x2]^2) Cos[x3] Sin[x1] Sin[x3] == a && 1/2 (1/2  Cos[x1] (-1 + 3 Cos[2 x1]) Cos[x2] Cos[x3] (-1 + 3 Cos[2 x3]) - 6 Cos[x1]^2 Cos[x3]^2 Sin[x1] Sin[x3] - 1/2  (1 + 3 Cos[2 x1]) Cos[x2]^2 (1 + 3 Cos[2 x3]) Sin[x1] Sin[x3] + 6  Cos[x1] Cos[x2]^3 Cos[x3] Sin[x1]^2 Sin[x3]^2) == -a, {x1, x2, x3, a}]
```

Comment: What do you want to maximize, what are underlying conditions?

Comment: I want to maximise a

Comment: And what about `x1, x2, x3` ? And what is `\[Eta]2`?

Comment: sorry \[Eta]2 is x2. Ill change that now. x1, x2, x3 have to be real

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original problem is an interesting example where a direct usage of `Solve` and `NSolve` fails. However `Reduce` can succeed solving it if we set unknowns in an appropriate order, thus there is no need to play with numerical functionality if symbolic one can resolve the given system. We can observe that there is a solution under the given condition with `a == 1/2`. We can do even more by demonstrating that there are only solutions in the real domain with `a <= 1/2` thus `a == 1/2` maximizes possible values of `a`.

Let's write down the underlying expressions

```
expr1 = Cos[x1] Cos[x2] Cos[x3] - Sin[x1] Sin[x3];
expr2 = Cos[x1]^2 Cos[x2] Cos[2 x3] - Cos[x2] Cos[2 x3] Sin[x1]^2 - 
        2 Cos[x1] (1 + Cos[x2]^2) Cos[x3] Sin[x1] Sin[x3];
expr3 = 1/2 (1/2 Cos[x1] (-1 + 3 Cos[2 x1]) Cos[x2] Cos[x3] (-1 + 3Cos[2 x3]) 
       - 6 Cos[x1]^2 Cos[x3]^2 Sin[x1] Sin[x3] - 
       1/2 (1 + 3 Cos[2 x1]) Cos[x2]^2 (1 + 3 Cos[2 x3]) Sin[x1] Sin[x3]
       + 6 Cos[x1] Cos[x2]^3 Cos[x3] Sin[x1]^2 Sin[x3]^2);
```

and the system is

```
system = expr1 == a && expr2 == a && expr3 == -a;
```

Since `expr1, expr2, expr3` are periodic functions with respect to  `x1, x2, x3` with  the `2Pi` period (we can easily check it with `FunctionPeriod` ) we restrict our seeking to the range `0 <= x1, x2, x3 <= 2Pi`, by supplementing `system` with  appropriate conditions. Moreover since there is a solution for `a == 1/2` we restrict the searching by adding the following condition `1/2 <= a <=1`.  The overall conditions are:

```
conditions = 1/2 <= a <= 1 && 
           0 <= x1 <= 2 Pi && 0 <= x2 <= 2 Pi && 0 <= x3 <= 2 Pi;
```

This yields a symbolic solution to the given problem.

```
sols = Reduce[ system && conditions, 
               {x1, x2, x3, a}, 
               Backsubstitution -> True];
```

Symbolic solutions can be very useful in various tasks however
we need not simplify them since we can just find their actual values:

```
N @ sols
```

> ```
> (x1 == 4.17595 && x2 == 3.55883 && x3 == 2.10724 && a == 0.5) ||
> (x1 == 4.17595 && x2 == 2.72436 && x3 == 2.10724 && a == 0.5) ||
> (x1 == 5.24883 && x2 == 3.55883 && x3 == 1.03435 && a == 0.5) ||
> (x1 == 5.24883 && x2 == 2.72436 && x3 == 1.03435 && a == 0.5) ||
> (x1 == 1.03435 && x2 == 3.55883 && x3 == 5.24883 && a == 0.5) ||
> (x1 == 1.03435 && x2 == 2.72436 && x3 == 5.24883 && a == 0.5) ||
> (x1 == 2.10724 && x2 == 3.55883 && x3 == 4.17595 && a == 0.5) ||
> (x1 == 2.10724 && x2 == 2.72436 && x3 == 4.17595 && a == 0.5)
> ```

In fact this demonstrates that the maximal value of `a` is `1/2`.

A bit more straightforward way way of calculating the maximum value of `a` is an approriate use of `NMaximize`, now we need not use the parameter `a` and the condition `1/2 <= a <=1`, thus we can get the value this way :

```
NMaximize[{ expr1, expr1 == expr2, expr1 + expr3 == 0, 
            Sequence @@ Rest@conditions}, {x1, x2, x3}]
```

> ```
>  {0.5, {x1 -> 4.1759, x2 -> 2.72436, x3 -> 2.10719}}
> ```

Recalling that with `NMaximize` we get the global maximum, it was sufficient to get only one instance of arguments `x1, x2, x3`.  For more information on this issue one can read these posts [How do I determine the maximum value for a polynomial, given a range of x values?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37225/how-do-i-determine-the-maximum-value-for-a-polynomial-given-a-range-of-x-values/37227#37227) and [How can I implement the method of Lagrange multipliers to find constrained extrema?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36847/how-can-i-implement-the-method-of-lagrange-multipliers-to-find-constrained-extre/36854#36854). The method with `Maximize` has the advantage that we don't need any conditions on `a`. Analogically we can get the minimal value with `NMinimize`.

Comment: Thank you for the help and sorry about the poorly worked question to begin with!