# How I can indicate the maximum point on a curve

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

```
y = r^2 (0.5) - r^3
```

I am trying to get maximum point on this graph from range 0 to 0.5. Can some one help??

```
Plot[y, {r, 0, 0.5}]
```

[image: This is the graph]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine the maximum value for a polynomial, given a range of x values?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37225/how-do-i-determine-the-maximum-value-for-a-polynomial-given-a-range-of-x-values)

Comment: Try `Maximize[{r^2 (0.5)  -  r^3, 0 <r < .5}, r]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
y = r^2 (0.5) - r^3;
max = NMaximize[{y, 0 < r < .5}, r]
pt = {r /. Last@max, First@max}
Plot[y, {r, 0, 0.5}, Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[pt]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it helped alot

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[r_] := r^2 (0.5) - r^3
```

An alternative approach to mark the interior local maxima of a differentiable function `f` using [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) + [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) + [`MeshStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html):

```
Plot[f[r], {r, 0, 0.5}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {If[f''[#] <= 0, f'[#], 1] &}, 
  Mesh -> {{0}},
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]
```

[image]

```
Normal[%] /. p_Point :> {p, Text["maximum", p[[1]], {-1, -1}]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With [`Callout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html).

```
y[x_] := x^2 (0.5) - x^3
max = Maximize[{y[r], 0 < r < .5}, r];
pt = {r /. Last@max, First@max};
```

Then

```
Show[
 Plot[y[r], {r, 0, .5}]
 , ListPlot[{Callout[pt, "Maximum"]}, PlotStyle -> Red]
 , PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Or of course set the derivative to $0$, and solve for $x$.