# How can I mark the maximum value in a plot?

Tags: plotting, maximum

How can I mark the maximum value in a graph?

The graph that I would like to determine its maximum value, is an output of the following program:

```
im[Δm_, Δa_, c_, κa_, κm_, λ_, ω_] := (
   c κa κa )/(
   4 (κa - (κa λ^2)/(κa^2 + (-Δa - ω)^2))^2 + 
    4 (Δa - ω - (λ^2 (Δa + ω))/(κa^2 + (-Δa - ω)^2))^2) - (
   c κa λ^2 κa)/(
   4 (κa^2 + (-Δa - ω)^2) ((κa - (κa λ^2)/(κa^2 + (-Δa - ω)^2))^2 + (Δa - ω - (λ^2 (Δa + ω))/(κa^2 + (-Δa - ω)^2))^2));

Plot[im[0.1 10, 1 10, 1000, 0.1 10, 0.000001 10, x, 0.1 10],
 {x, 0.980 10, 1.016 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"λ/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(κ\), \(a\)]\)",
    "-Im[\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Σ\), \(m\)]\)(ω)]/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(κ\), \(m\)]\)" }, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `Maximize[{im[0.1 10, 1 10, 1000, 0.1 10, 0.000001 10, x, 0.1 10], 
  x > 0}, x]`

Comment: dupe: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/237109/4999

Answer (score 9):

```
f[x_] := im[0.1 10, 1 10, 1000, 0.1 10, 0.000001 10, x, 0.1 10];
```

**1.** An alternative way to use [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html):

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0.980 10, 1.016 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"λ/" <> ToString[Subscript[κ, a], StandardForm], 
   "-Im[" <> ToString[Subscript[Σ, m], StandardForm] <> 
    "(ω)]/" <> ToString[Subscript[κ, m], StandardForm]},
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], PlotStyle -> Blue, 
 MeshFunctions -> {f'}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize @ Large]]
```

[image]

**2.** We can also insert the desired primitives using the option `DisplayFunction`:

```
displayFunction = Show[#,
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize @ Large, 
   Point[MaximalBy[Last][Join @@ Cases[Normal@#, Line[x_] :> x, All]]]}] &


Plot[f[x], {x, 0.980 10, 1.016 10}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Blue, 
 DisplayFunction -> displayFunction]
```

[image]

Comment: see also [this answer by Silvia](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46532/125)

Answer (score 7):

You may e.g. use "NMaximize" and "Epilog" like:

```
pt = NMaximize[{im[0.1 10, 1 10, 1000, 0.1 10, 0.000001 10, x, 
    0.1 10], 9 < x < 10}, x]
pt = {x, pt[[1]]} /. pt[[2, 1]];
Plot[im[0.1 10, 1 10, 1000, 0.1 10, 0.000001 10, x, 0.1 10], {x, 
  0.980 10, 1.016 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\[Lambda]/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Kappa]\), \(a\)]\)",
    "-Im[\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[CapitalSigma]\), \
\(m\)]\)(\[Omega])]/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Kappa]\), \(m\)]\)"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], PlotStyle -> Blu, 
 Epilog -> Line[{{pt[[1]], 0}, pt}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
fm = FindMaximum[
   im[0.1 10, 1 10, 1000, 0.1 10, 0.000001 10, x, 0.1 10], {x, 10}];
coord = {fm[[2, 1, 2]], fm[[1]]};
Show[{
  Plot[im[0.1 10, 1 10, 1000, 0.1 10, 0.000001 10, x, 0.1 10], {x, 
    0.980 10, 1.016 10}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Text1", "Text2"}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], PlotStyle -> Blue],
  Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[coord]}]
  }]
```

yielding the following plot:

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

You could do it in different ways, one solution is using the `Mesh` option in the plot:

Use `NArgMax` to find the maximum value of `x` and use that value in the mesh to highlight the maximimum point.

### Code

```
Plot[im[0.1 10, 1 10, 1000, 0.1 10, 0.000001 10, x, 0.1 10], {x, 
  0.980 10, 1.016 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\[Lambda]/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Kappa]\), \(a\)]\)",
    "-Im[\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[CapitalSigma]\), \
\(m\)]\)(\[Omega])]/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Kappa]\), \(m\)]\)"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], PlotStyle -> Blue, 

 Mesh -> {{NArgMax[{im[0.1 10, 1 10, 1000, 0.1 10, 0.000001 10, x, 
       0.1 10], 0.980 10 <= x <= 1.016 10}, x]}}, MeshStyle -> {Red,PointSize[Medium]}]
```

Result:
[image]