# Symbolic solution to a constrained optimization problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization, symbolic

Can anyone tell me why this method ([Symbolic Constrained Optimization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41837/symbolic-constrained-optimization)) works but not the following for obtaining symbolic solutions of a constrained optimization problem:

```
MaxValue[{a^(1/2)*(y - p*q)^(1/2) + d*(1/2)*(Q + q - a), 
  a <= Q + q &&  q <= y/p &&  q >= 0 &&  a >= 0}, {a, q}]
```

But it freezes, so I assign some values to the parameters:

```
y = 50
p = 2
d = 0.95
MaxValue[{a^(1/2)*(y - p*q)^(1/2) + d*(1/2)*(Q + q - a), 
  a <= Q + q &&  q <= y/p &&  q >= 0 &&  a >= 0}, {a, q}]

Out = MaxValue[{Sqrt[a] Sqrt[50 - 2 q] + 0.475 (-a + q + Q), 
  a <= q + Q && q <= 25 && q >= 0 && a >= 0}, {a, q}]
```

Comment: I guess that the square roots are the main obstruction for using symbolic optimization. In the second example, `Q` still has no numerical value assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an exact value for `d` (or [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html))

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

y = 50;
p = 2;
d = 95/100;

f[Q_] = MaxValue[{a^(1/2)*(y - p*q)^(1/2) + d*(1/2)*(Q + q - a), a <= Q + q, 
   q <= y/p, q >= 0, a >= 0}, {a, q}]//Simplify
```

[image]

```
Plot[f[Q], {Q, -50, 100}]
```

[image]