# How can I calculate Lagrange multiplier and the critical points with Mathematica?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have constraints and a function I want to know the critic points but is there a way that I can compute this method so that I can see results faster

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please provide more detail, including code you may have developed.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36847/, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78400/, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41837/