# What methods does Maximize use like $\mathtt{Maximize}\left[\left\{3 x^2+2 \sqrt{2} x y,x^4+y^4=1\right\},\{x,y\}\right]$

Tags: mathematical-optimization, implementation-details

I used `Maximize` for the maximum value of $3 x^2+2 \sqrt{2} x y$ when $x^4+y^4=1$ , $x>0,y>0$.

1. What methods does `Maximize` of *Mathematica* use?
2. Could you show me the processes with the Lagrange multiplier?

> ```
> Maximize[{3 x^2 + 2 Sqrt[2] x y, x^4 + y^4 == 1}, {x, y}]
>
> {2 Sqrt[5], {x -> Root[-4 + 5 #1^4 &, 1], 
>  y -> (2 Sqrt[5] - 3 Root[-4 + 5 #1^4 &, 1]^2)/
>  (2 Sqrt[2] Root[-4 + 5 #1^4 &, 1])
> }}
> ```

Comment: There is [the Lagrange method of multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), see e.g. this answer [How can I implement the method of Lagrange multipliers to find constrained extrema?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36847/how-can-i-implement-the-method-of-lagrange-multipliers-to-find-constrained-extre/36854#36854). This does not mean that behind the scene it is implemented exactly the way as in the linked anser.  See also [Some Notes on Internal Implementation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html)

Comment: For a simpler form of your result use `ToRadicals`, i.e., `Maximize[{3 x^2 + 2 Sqrt[2] x y, x^4 + y^4 == 1}, {x, y}] // ToRadicals // Quiet`

Comment: How to proceed  with that method you can find in the linked answer. Is it really unclear therein?

Comment: @Artes  Thanks a lot. I got it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To your 2. question (shortly):

```
f = 3 x^2 + 2 Sqrt[2] x y;
g = x^4 + y^4 - 1;
L = f + λ g;

points = NSolve[{Grad[L, {x, y}] == 0, g == 0, x > 0, y > 0}, {x,y, λ}, Reals]
{{x -> 0.945742, y -> 0.66874, λ -> -2.23607}}

f /. points
{4.47214}
```

with `NMaximize`

```
NMaximize[{3 x^2 + 2 Sqrt[2] x y, x^4 + y^4 == 1}, {x, y}]
{4.47214, {x -> 0.945742, y -> 0.66874}}
```