# Augmented function of function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector-calculus

I have two generic  functions :

```
ucdu[x : {__}] := Times @@ (x)
```

and

```
cb[x : {__}, p : {__}] := Plus @@ (x p)
```

For instance, they can be applied to vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$

```
nv = 3;
xx = Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, nv}](*{Subscript[x, 1], ...., Subscript[x, nv]}*);
pp = Table[Subscript[p, i], {i, 1, nv}](*{Subscript[p, 1], ...., Subscript[p, nv]}*);
ucdu[xx]
cb[xx, pp]
```

which give :

$x_1 x_2 x_3$ and $x_1 p_1+ x_2 p_2 + x_3 p_3$

Now, I want to write a new function, say a Lagrangian, with one more variable  say $\mathcal{L}[xx, pp, \lambda] = ucdu[xx]- \lambda (cb[xx, pp]- R)$. $\mathcal{L}$ must be generic enough to be called on other functions --- for instance, $ucdg[xx,\alpha\alpha]$...

I have tried

```
ll[u_Symbol, cb_Symbol, λ_, xx_, pp_] := u - λ (cb - R)
```

but `ll[ucdu[xx], cb[xx, pp], λ]` returns $ll[x_1 x_2 x_3, x_1 p_1 + x_2 p_2+ x_3 p_3, \lambda,\{x_1, x_2, x_3\},\{p_1, p_2, p_3\}]$ not $x_1 x_2 x_3 - \lambda(-R + x_1 p_1 + x_2 p_2+ x_3 p_3)$

What am I doing wrong? Later I want to write the `Gradient` with respect of `Join[xx,{\lambda}]`

Comment: Well, for one you are not calling your function `ll` with enough arguments. If you define it to take five arguments, of course it will return unevaluated if you call it with three. Also, notice that the return value of `ucdu[xx]` has head `Times`, so it won't match the `_Symbol` pattern restriction you put in the definition. If you redefine `ll` without the pattern restrictions, and include any expression for `xx_` and `pp_` (their value doesn't seem to matter, since you don't use them in the definition of `ll`), then it will evaluate. Whether the return value is correct though, I am not sure.

Comment: You might also be interested in [How can I implement the method of Lagrange multipliers?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36847/27951).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your function definitions in place, and using indexed variables rather than subscripts:

```
nv = 3;
xx = Table[x[i], {i, 1, nv}];
pp = Table[p[i], {i, 1, nv}];

Clear[ll]
ll[f_, g_, xvar_, pvar_, lambda_] := f[xvar] - lambda (g[xvar, pvar] - r)

ll[ucdu, cb, xx, pp, lambda]

(* Out: x[1] x[2] x[3] - lambda (-r + p[1] x[1] + p[2] x[2] + p[3] x[3]) *)
```

That seems to be your intended result.

Comment: MarcoB Thanks. It works also with indexes.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[ll2]
ll2[u_, cb_,  λ_] := u - λ(cb - r)

ll2[ucdu[xx], cb[xx, pp], λ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]